# Onclick function is not called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I spent significant time on solving one issue in JavaScript. The code snippet is as bellow. The details of other part of html, `Form` and `Table` is omitted in this post.

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Save Customer" onclick="SaveData" />

<script lang="javascript">

function BindData(Data)
{
    $("#status").text("Loading......");
    //This removes all other rows except first
    tbl.find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
    //More logic is there to fill a table
 }

function SaveData()
{
    $("#status").text("Adding data. Please wait......");
    var frm = $("#frmCustomer").serialize();
    $.post("Submit", frm, BindData);
}

</script>
```

The syntax for onclick event in HTML is defined at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) as :

```
<element onclick="myScript">
```

I took my code from the link (thinking to be authentic) and over-looked it afterwards. Now, this has raised another point: Why it is mandatory to provide `()` after function name? 2 characters could have been saved had syntax allowed to mention just function name(Obviously for functions with no argument).

Comment: `onclick="SaveData()"`? https://jsfiddle.net/2y6s80cz/

Comment: Is there a reason you're mixing inline events and jquery?

Comment: Silly me. Kept on overlooking that. Perhaps many function calls from jquery had set my mind to think of function without (). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the parenthesis in your `onclick`.

```
onclick="SaveData()"
```

**NOTE:** You're already using jQuery so you don't need to use inline events. You could totally remove your `onclick="SaveData()"` and do:

```
function BindData(Data) {
  // ...
}

function SaveData() {
  // ...
}

$('#btn').on('click', SaveData);
```

Worth noting, the first argument of any event handler function (in this case, your `SaveData` function) will be the event object containing things like where the event came from, etc.

For more about event handling you can read about [jQuery `.on()` here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).